# Talend How to concatenate multiple tables records in a json file

Tags: json, merge, concatenation, talend

In Talend I would like to produce one json file with rows from 4 tables.
Firstly I did 4 json files one for each table, it works, but how can I merge them ? I tried to iterate with tfilelist but I dont know how to use it, even with Talend documentation.
Or can I directly put my 4 tables rows directly in a big json file ?

My final json file have to be like this :

```
[
{ records of table 1 }
{ records of table 1 }
...
{ records of table 2 }
{ records of table 2 }
...
{ records of table 3 }
{ records of table 3 }
...
{ records of table 4 }
{ records of table 4 }
...
]
```

In other words a concatenation of each table records in a json format

Here is my job at the moment (4 json generated ok)

[image: Job]

I try to iterate over the files to concatenate their json records but The error is "No schema defined yet", I dont know which schema to put in....

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange job as follows...

[image]

and tFileList properties as,
[image]

and tFileInputDelimited properties as,
[image]
and tFileOutputDelimited properties as ,
please enable the append checkbox as mentioned in below picture,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly, it'd take the following approach:

Create the four json files (one for each table) and save them to the globalMap (via the tSetGlobalVar component or via java code).
When that's done use a tFixedflow component, creating one line of data. This row should contain the four json-objects from the globalmap.

You can create one big JSON object from the four small ones with a tExtractJSONFields (or similar components).

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to tExtractJSONFields ( I updated original post )

Answer (score 0):

Your job looks good. Just to add, While iterating Files using tFileList, use ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")) in the tFileJsonInput as file path.

hope this help..

Comment: Thanks for your help but to be more precise I updated original post... also because of my error message